# error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, swing

I am working with swings. This is the code I used to make a frame for logout which would return a int value and using that value other operation could be performed in the previous function. But I am getting an error. How should I solve it?

```
 public int logout()
{ 
int s=0;
    JFrame main=new JFrame("Logout");
    Dimension d=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
main.setSize(d.width/2,d.height/3);
main.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JButton yes=new JButton("Yes");
main.add(yes); main.setVisible(true);   
    yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)
    {
        s=1;
    main.setVisible(false);
    }
    });

    return s;
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear if you ask me. If you want to reference a variable in an inner class it must be final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) class to create a confirm dialog by using one of the `showConfirmDialog()` method to show a confirm dialog. Please read the Java tutorial [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) on how to create such dialogs. The source code should look something like this:

```
int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(your_main_frame,
                                           "Do you want to logout?",
                                           "Logout?",
                                           JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // "Yes" clicked
} else {
    // "No" clicked
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you expect your program to do?

The code you wrote, tries to do:

- Create a "logout" frame with a "yes" button.
- Return from the logout() method with the value of the `s` variable.
- When **later** the user presses the "yes" button, you prepared an action listener to **then** set the `s` variable to `1` - but that can't work, as you already returned from the `logout()` method, and the variable `s` no longer even exists.

So, be happy that the compiler told you about a problem.

I suppose you want to wait for the user's logout approvement. Then use `JOptionPane` methods (the Java tutorials will help you how to do that correctly).

And by the way: get into the habit of formatting and indenting your code properly. It wasn't fun reading your code.

Comment: Tip to make it more pretty: if you're using an IDE like Eclipse (hopefully you do, it makes life much easier), there are one-click functions to "prettify" your code: Source/Correct Indentation and Source/Format.

Comment: *"I don't use Eclipse"* What software **do** you use to write / edit Java code?